# Hudson - Install as windows service Initialisation failure

Tags: hudson

Hudson - Install as Windows Service 
I am trying to install hudson build server on a windows xp. Path to the Hudson folder in the `E:\Hudson`. The Hudson directory contains the hudson.war file. I use the following command to navigate to Hudson dashboard.

```
java -jar E:\hudon\Hudson.war.
```

Then I can navigate to `http://localhost:8080`.

Now the problem is when I try to Install as Windows Service it is thrwoing the below exception.

```
**Installing a service
[hudsonhome] $ D:\hudsonhome\hudson.exe install
System.Management.ManagementException: Initialization failure 
   at System.Management.ManagementException.ThrowWithExtendedInfo(ManagementStatus errorCode)
   at System.Management.ManagementScope.InitializeGuts(Object o)
   at System.Management.ManagementScope.Initialize()
   at System.Management.ManagementScope.Connect()
   at WMI.WmiRoot..ctor(String machineName)
   at WMI.WmiRoot..ctor()
   at winsw.WrapperService.Run(String[] _args)
   at winsw.WrapperService.Main(String[] args)**
```

Is there any one who faced the same issue. Why it is throwing such an exception?

Comment: What about additional Slave(s)? Do u manage to install them or are facing the arhaic issue with JLNP?

Comment: Anyone can comment on this solution: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-4929 [ last comment ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only case of "Initialization failure" I know about (regarding WMI) is when the WMI repository is corrupted: see "[Rebuilding WMI Repository](http://www.functioncore.com/blog/rebuilding-wmi-repository/)".
Your context is a bit different, and the script detailed in the article might not be the right one for you, but before executing any script anyway, it is still worth to check if the [WMI repo is corrupted or not](http://myitforum.com/cs2/blogs/jgilbert/archive/2008/01/11/how-to-check-the-wmi-repository-before-rebuilding-it.aspx), before [attempting to rebuild it](http://windowsxp.mvps.org/repairwmi.htm).

Comment: Exactly this was the problem. I rebuilt Wmi and the problem solved. Thank you so much.